# How use different versions of PHP in command line

Tags: php, macos

I'm facing an issue. I've multiple projects thats using different version of PHP. I world like to have a way to define for example:

- sites/project1 -> php 5.6
- sites/project2 -> php 7.0
- sites/project3 ->
  php 7.1

I'm currently using MAMP PRO to manage web-server but my issue is regarding to command line.

I don't want to use docker or vagrant for each project just configure a specific binary php per project folder.

Is there a way to do that?

Best!

Comment: I don't understand what you actually ask: if this is about the command line, then why do you see an issue in "configuring a specific binary php per project"? You just specify it using a path on the command line. That's it.

Comment: Yes basically I'm working in multiples project that needs work on different version of php. For some reason, the option you mentioned doesn't work, if run php -v I see always the binaries that comes with macOS.

Comment: You did not understand what I suggest. You chose the version of php by the path. It is up to you which version you chose for each project that way. Example: `/usr/bin/php71` will launch version 7.1, whilst `/usr/bin/php-5.6` might launch version 5.6. The paths obviously depend on how you installed the different versions.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I totally understand your answer. Is there a way to reference a different binary per directory? that was my original question. Thanks again :)

Comment: Easiest would be to modify a `PATH` environment variable or maybe an ``alias`` definition. Although I still don't understand the need here. If you manually start a process you need to explicitly call the executable anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [phpbrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew), it's very simple and convenient when you want to switch between PHP versions as well as for PHP extension management.

For changing the PHP CLI version you just run one command:

```
$ phpbrew list
* php-7.1.12
  php-5.5.15

$ php -v
PHP 7.1.12 (cli) (built: Jan 14 2018 22:25:40) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.1.12, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

$ phpbrew use php-5.5.15
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.15 (cli) (built: Nov  9 2018 00:22:21)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use MAMP your php bin files are located under:

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php*.*.*/bin/php`

I can recommend to create alias/symbolic link for each PHP version

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.12/bin/php => php7.1`

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6/bin/php => php5.6`

etc..